# Authentication failure using docker - su

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, passwords, multi-user

I am using the `docker` ubuntu image and logging in as `root`.

1- Set root password: `passwd root` and success;

2- Adduser testaccount : `adduser testaccount`;

3- Change user to test account:`su - testaccount` , which is ok;

4- After step 3, it is testaccount bash.

After I run this : `su - root` and insert password(correct password) 
get a error :

> su: Authentication failure

Do you know why ?

Comment: after that i install ssh, and use ssh login as root, that all right

Comment: None of these things are typical to do at all in Docker.  If you need a root shell in a container (should be unusual) you can `docker exec` to get it, and that doesn't have password authentication.  Similarly, running a bare `ubuntu` image usually doesn't have much value since everything you've described here will be lost as soon as the container exits.  Docker's [Getting Started, Part 2: Containers](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/) tutorial describes a much more typical Docker-based application setup.

Comment: @DavidMaze i am really understand about pv . this case is i am trying make my own image for small companies，they want use ubuntu in cloud as usual.  i want make same accout to people without root privilege. but I need to maintain these image

Comment: @DavidMaze i am confused about that . i remember that is right at ubuntu , but why it not works on docker. do you know that?

Comment: Think of Docker as a way to package a single process: Docker containers of Nginx, or MySQL, or a single Python application are very common.  If you want a full Ubuntu environment with passwords and remote ssh, a virtual machine is a much better match.